# https npm module installed, but no files shown in the node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, npm, https

I installed the https npm module in a node.js application, but I cannot see any files in the node_modules directory under https folder. How can I view the files inside the https package?

Comment: Are you looking for the folder in your text editor or inside folder structure on your local machine?

Comment: I tried both inside the node_modules in my project and also inside the .nvm/https folder in my local machine

Comment: var http = require('http');  in this require module where does the http module exist, or can I see the files inside the module

Comment: Oh, that is not module. http is a part of Node. Check this out https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Then how can I edit any of the files in that?

Comment: This is just for a debugging process

Comment: I do not think you can edit node's files. And even for node modules you should not do that. It is a really bad idea. You should eather use modules as they are, or fork them if you want something new, or create pull request on npm module's github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201670/discussion-between-sabreena-and-lazar-nikolic).